# I can't find the mistake in Convert From Base64 String

Tags: c#, base64, decode

I'm try make a Convert From Base64 String. I read about base64 be `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=` This is my string:

> 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

I cant find a different chatter. Always are between the acceptable chatters.

I my code i do:

```
String codedBody = emailClass.Body.Replace("-", "+");
codedBody = codedBody.Replace("_", "/");
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(codedBody);
emailClass.Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

When i run the line `byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(codedBody);` I receive the exeption:

> {"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."}

[image]

I use de [Repair Base64](https://base64.guru/tools/repair) and the site split my string in two valid base64Strings.

> 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

> 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

Is This a rule ? When I have a `=` i slip my string ?

Comment: I must ask, after decoding the following myself, just for debugging purposes, what is the very end supposed to be?

Comment: I'm read my emails in this code to create a personal email manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using the regex `([a-zA-Z0-9\+\/]*={0,3})` to get a valid Base64String.
Later i add de Base64Strings.

```
String codedBody = emailClass.Body.Replace("-", "+");
codedBody = codedBody.Replace("_", "/");
byte[] DataBody = new byte[0];

try
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(codedBody);
    DataBody = AddBiteArray(DataBody, data);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var GetBase64Maches = _regexTOGetBase64.Matches(codedBody);
    
    foreach(Match Base64StringMatch in GetBase64Maches)
    {
        var Base64String = Base64StringMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);
        DataBody = AddBiteArray(DataBody, data);
    }

}

emailClass.Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DataBody);
```

The codedBody is:

```
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
```

and :

```
static byte[] AddBiteArray(Byte[] destino, Byte[] origem)
{
    var retorno = new Byte[destino.Length + origem.Length];
    destino.CopyTo(retorno, 0);
    origem.CopyTo(retorno, destino.Length);
    return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit my way needs improving but how I solved this issue is splitting mid string based on the "=" and then just append "=" onto each of the new strings, creating a simple string array with both base64 values then you can just do your normal base64 decode and you have it done!

[Demo](https://replit.com/@jmorris002/TalkativeSnoopyDisc#main.cs)

Comment: If you split on `=`, all those symbols are removed from the resulting strings. Then you'd have to check the Length of each string and append `=` chars until the length can be divided by 4. e.g., `int missing = 4 - ([Part].Length % 4); if (missing > 0 && missing != 4) parts[i] += new string('=', missing);`